# Can I access HTTP header this way?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

So I've been trying to create token based authentication in `Java EE` lately and I tried to sent token via HTTP Header, but failed so many times.

**My question** : If I have for example `@POST` response method and I set header via return response statement 
`return Response.ok(entity).header(HttpHeader.AUTHORIZATION, authToken).build()`

Then I invoke other method that was binded to `ContainerRequestFilter` and in this filter I try to access header via 
`ContainerRequestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)`
 then should it work?

Will I get the value from that header that was set in response method? If not then what should I do to get value of this header in filter method?

Comment: Filters are used to filter the incoming request... usually authorisation will happen before reach the rest api handler method... authorisation header should be along with authorisation header.

Comment: Improved explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Authorization` header(or any other header) must be included by the client in each request

Your client should get the token from the server response, keep it in a secure storage and set the Authorization header when performs a request. Then, with `RequestContextFilter` your server will be able to recover it